# Cannot access EC2 Flask application hosted by Gunicorn and Nginx from Public IPv4 address

Tags: nginx, flask, networking, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I cannot access my EC2 Flask web app from my browser. I'm using Gunicorn and have confirmed that it is hosting my app. The command I used to run it is below:

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 app:app
```

I also have a Nginx file that includes a proxy_pass:

```
upstream myapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
} 

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    proxy_pass http://myapp;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

I've confirmed that the Nginx server is running as well. I also checked that the inbound rules for my security group is set to all traffic:
[image]

Can anyone help explain what might be the problem and any ways to debug it? Any help is greatly appreciated!